# How to insert unsubscribe link to automatically generated PHPMailer email?

Tags: php, email

I'm using PHPMailer to send in a newsletter from my website which works fine. Of course, I'd like to add an unsubscribe link at the end of each email, which I'm also successfully able to do, generating user specific codes and so forth. I have isHTML set to true.

The problem is that once I send the email, Yahoo, for example, puts a class `"nofollow"` on every link present in the email, including the unsubscribe one. As a result, the links become unclickable and users are not able to access them. I've tried using `<unsubscribe>` tags but with no success.

Any ideas how I can make sure that users will be able to click on the links that I send?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142935/how-to-generate-unsubscribe-link-for-newsletter

Comment: This is not even similar to the question that I asked. I'm able to successfully generate unsubscrirbe codes and send them to the users. My problem is that email clients such as Yahoo remove all links from the messages that I generate so users cannot follow them.

Comment: _“Yahoo, for example, puts a class "nofollow" on every link present in the email”_ – and how exactly is that problematic?

Comment: The 'nofollow' disables the link so the user is not able to click on it.